# How do I add the Customer Price Class to the SO Screen on Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am trying to include the Customer Price Class on the SO screen. The Price Class filed is located in

```
Customer> Delivery Settings> Default Location Settings > Price Class
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

`location` data-view is defined in the `Sales Order` which is getting `Location` of the `Sales Order`s `Customer`.
 Price Class ID is stored in the `Location` DAC. So you can use it for showing Price Class ID of the customer.
You need to do the following steps for achieving that:

1. Add new `Form` to the `Form: Document`  and set `DataMember` to `location`:

[image]

2. Add `Price Class` field to that newly added form:

[image]

3. Set the `RenderStyle` Of the form to `Simple` so that it doesn't render it as a form:

[image]

After these steps you will get `Price Class` field on the `Sales Order` Page as below:

[image]

Comment: wow thank you so much!!! it worked!! Is there a way to line up the Price Class with the other fields so they are all aligned or a mi asking for too much?

Comment: @NitaRab you might play with the Properties of the field. I can't say for sure how to align it with other fields. But it seems like Acumatica is adding some padding to the form and it is moving the field to the center.

Comment: For some reason I cant publish this customization. The validation fails. The error I am getting:

Validating Binary Files
Validating the website XXXXX
Building directory '\WebSiteValidationDomain\App_RuntimeCode\'.
\WebSiteValidationDomain\App_RuntimeCode\folder.runtime(1): error ASPPARSE: The type initializer for 'PX.Data.PXCodeDirectoryCompiler' threw an exception.
The type initializer for 'PX.Data.PXCodeDirectoryCompiler' threw an exception.
Compiler time, in seconds: 0.2968583
Validation failed.

Comment: Hi Samvel, The customization will not publish because validation fails. Can you please advise ?

Comment: @NitaRab I don't know what you have changed in your customization. I would advise you to open separate question and post there all the changes you have done in customization.